# Draw Amplitudes by time Audio Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to draw a spectral representation of some recorded audio.
Using the AudioRecord class, i get an array of bytes with amplitude values i guess.

Now the problem is that i don't know how to represent the time axis.

Any ideas??

Recording code:

```
 public void startRecording(View v) {
    mIsRecording = true;
    mRecorder.startRecording();


    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

                while (mIsRecording) {
                    int readSize = mRecorder.read(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.length);

                }

        }
    }).start();
}
```

Recorder init:

```
private void initRecorder() {
    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    mBuffer = new short[bufferSize];
    mRecorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you talk about spectrum you are referring the frequency components of an audio signal, which is very different from the amplitude.

Anyway if you want to plot the amplitude over time, the *x-axis* will be the time while the *y-axis* the amplitude. The key value here is the **sample rate**, which defines how many samples per second you are recording; you need to decide how many time you want to plot the *mean amplitude value* on screen (in relation to the sample rate) and then...just draw it. I suggest you to start by something simpler, like the following example from the [Samsung official docs](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000086):

> ```
> AudioRecord recorder; // our recorder, must be initialized first
> short[] buffer; // buffer where we will put captured samples
> DataOutputStream output; // output stream to target file
> boolean isRecording; // indicates if sound is currently being captured
> ProgressBar pb; // our progress bar recieved from layout
> while (isRecording) {
>   double sum = 0;
>   int readSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
>   for (int i = 0; i < readSize; i++) {
>       output.writeShort(buffer [i]);
>       sum += buffer [i] * buffer [i];
>   }
>   if (readSize > 0) {
>       final double amplitude = sum / readSize;
>       pb.setProgress((int) Math.sqrt(amplitude));
>   }
> }
> ```

This example shows the real-time amplitude value (using a `ProgressBar`); you can adapt this example and draw the amplitude values in sequence over time (e.g. drawing consecutive vertical lines in a `Canvas`)