# Draw profile of the mic input

Tags: java, audio, waveform

I don't know much about sounds digitalization. I am trying to represent the instant profile of the mic input. I know how to get the bits from the mic, but I don't know how to interpret it into a profile. Can anyone help me filling the blank?

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 *
 * @author François Billioud
 */
public class SoundRecorder extends JFrame {

    /** JFrame for the GUI **/
    public SoundRecorder() {
        super("Sound Recorder");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pane.add(wavePane = new WavePane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pane.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("ok") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
            }
        }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setSize(300,300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    /** Just displays the frame and starts listening **/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SoundRecorder rec = new SoundRecorder();
                rec.setVisible(true);
                rec.listenToMic();
            }
        });
    }

    /** Draws the sound read from the mic **/
    private static class WavePane extends JPanel {
        private final int[] x = new int[0];
        private int[] y = new int[0];
        private WavePane() {
            setOpaque(true);
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        /** updates the data to be displayed **/
        public void setData(int[] y) {
            this.y = y;
            int n = y.length;
            this.x = new int[n];
            float pas = getWidth()/(float)(n-1);
            float xCurrent = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                this.x[i] = Math.round(xCurrent);
                xCurrent+=pas;
            }
            repaint();
        }
        /** Draws a line that represent the mic profile **/
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2D.drawPolyline(x, y, x.length);
        }
    }

    /** Defines the audio format to be used.
     * I know nothing about that and am open to suggestions if needed
     */
    private static final AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(
            16000, //Sample rate
            16, //SampleSizeInBits
            2, //Channels
            true,//Signed
            true //BigEndian
    );

    /** Creates a thread that will read data from
     * the mic and send it to the WavePane
     * in order to be painted.
     * We should be using a SwingWorker, but it will do
     * for the sake of this demo.
     **/
    private void listenToMic() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //Open the line and read
                    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

                    //checks if system supports the data line
                    if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
                        System.err.print("Line not supported");
                    }

                    //starts listening
                    TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                    line.open(format);
                    line.start();

                    //sends the stream to the interpreter
                    AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(line);
                    AudioSystem.write(ais, AudioFileFormat.Type.AU, new Interpreter());
                } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException ex) {
                    System.err.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private final WavePane wavePane;
    private class Interpreter extends OutputStream {
        private int[] y;

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            //TBD

            //Fill y array
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() throws IOException {
            //Sends the values found to the panel for drawing
            wavePane.setData(y);
        }

    }

}
```

I found [this link](https://github.com/Radiodef/WaveformDemo/blob/master/waveformdemo/WaveformDemo.java) but it didn't help me...

**Edit:** Ok, from what I understand, each 16 bits is the amplitude for one frequency. I have 2 channels, so I have to read 16 bits every 32 to get the first channel. Now I need to know how many frequencies I am going to read for each frame. Then I think I can draw the profile. Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw the spectrum (energy per frequency over time) of the signal that is coming from the microphone then you might want to read [this](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Time_Frequency_Displays.html). Maybe a bit more that you wanted to know but it has the maths you need.

If you want to draw the amplitude (the pressure over time) then check, for instance, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33419122/draw-amplitudes-by-time-audio-android).

The contents of the audio stream, based on your specification of the audio format, will be a PCM stream. PCM stream means that every frame is a value of sound pressure at that moment of time. Each frame will consist of four bytes, two bytes per channel. The first two bytes will be channel 0, the other two -- channel 1. The two bytes will be in big endian format (the more significant byte will come before the less significant byte). The fact that you specified signed as True means that you should interpret the values as being in the range from -32768 to 32767.

Comment: Thank you for your very complete link. I want to draw the energy per frequency from the mic in real time. Your link is good, but the STFT is done when converting the mic input into bits. The question is more about how the data is arranged in the stream when I read them, and how I should reorder them in order to get my representation. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Added some comment about the stream contents to the answer.

Comment: Ok. I think I only a few more information then, how should I interpret a negative number? Energy can't be negative, so I guess that -3000 means 3000 with a phase of PI? So, should I just consider the absolute value then? If I have a byte array `byte[16]` in big endian unsigned format, what is the correct way to transform it into a number? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You can think of PCM data as deviation of the air pressure from normal at given points of time. Thus, positive values mean that the pressure is higher than normal, negative values -- that the pressure is lower. To convert a 16-byte array to a single number in Java, pass it to the constructor of the BigInteger class. For your input format, though, 16 bytes would constitute 4 frames. The first frame would be in bytes 0-3. The sample value of the first channel in that frame would be in bytes 0 and 1 and the actual value of the sample would be byte[0] * 256 + byte[1].